# PyQt5 how to set QLineEdit behaviour like '\n'

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyqt5, qlineedit

The answer is probably really simple but I searched like 30 mins and couldn't find anything. I just want to set QLineEdit like what does `\n` do. To be more specific, when I start to type in QLineEdit, if it's a long sentence and bigger than the width of QLineEdit, it's going straight like forever. I want to start it on a new line when the text is reach end of the QLineEdit box. Even I press enter while typing, it does not go to a new line. How can I fix this? Is QLineEdit only 1 row and doesn't go bottom line?

Comment: Read the first line of [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html).

Comment: @BrenBarn Yep as I thought, then is there a method like what I want like QLineEdit?

Comment: Perhaps [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html), or perhaps try googling for what you specifically need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Line" is right there in its name, so yes, it supports "only 1 row".

> The [QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#details) widget is a one-line text editor.

What you want is [`QPlainTextEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html) or [`QTextEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) if you need styling.